# GitHub can't connect to IntelliJ after updating to 2017.3.3

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I've just tried to update my IntelliJ to version 2017.3.3 and I can no longer fetch or pull into my GitHub repos. It will first prompt me with this screen:

[image]

Then, I will correctly enter my credentials, after which it will prompt me with this one:

[image]

And then it will go back and forth between those two, with me correctly entering my credentials, until finally it alerts me with:

[image]

I've checked through a browser, I'm able to log in and out of Git with the credentials I'm using in Intellij. I've also checked in IntelliJ File | Settings | Version Control | GitHub and running a test, having it prompt me for the two factor authentication. That returns a success from IntelliJ. Any idea on what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

"NOTICE: Experiencing GitHub push/fetch problems?
As of 22 Feb 2018, GitHub has disabled support for weak encryption which means many users will suddenly find themselves unable to authenticate using a Git for Windows which (impacts versions older than v2.16.0). DO NOT PANIC, there's a fix. Update Git for Windows to the latest (or at least v2.16.0)."

You need to update the Git Credentials Manager and possibly Git itself.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases I installed the newest release here and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the second prompt is issued by the credential-helper configured in the git client itself. Does `git fetch` work from the command line?

I would recommend unsetting all gi credential helpers and let IntelliJ manage your passwords. See e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git) to unset them

Comment: `git fetch ` from Git Bash command line prompts me with the "white" login prompt posted above. After typing in my credentials, it says `fatal: HttpRequestException encountered, 'An error occurred while sending the request.`. Doing `git fetch` from IntelliJ prompts me from there alone for credentials, but again says `remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for <repository>`. I just tried logging into GitHub just through a browser, making a small change, & was able to commit it no problem. Tried unsetting with the windows CredentialManager, but Git isn't listed there

Comment: What worked with IntelliJ was to make a switch in the settings, I had it ask me to use a Token instead of the password. Now I'm able to pull there, but still locked out from any command line stuff.